# Performance loop with integer vs Long index

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, long-integer

I am wondering why it takes so much longer to run a loop with a long index vs. an integer index?

Any idea?

Thanks

```
int n = 1000_000_000;
long n2 =n;
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for( int idx = 0; idx<n;idx++){

}
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for( long idx = 0; idx<n2;idx++){

}
long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long dt1 = t2-t1;
long dt2 = t3-t2;
System.out.println("with int = took " + dt1 +"ms");
System.out.println("with long = took " + dt2 +"ms");
```

Comment: I forgot the output: with int = took 3ms
with long = took 337ms

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1679863)

Comment: Are you saying something is not correct?

Comment: Such loops could be optimized by the hotspot compiler (especially with many iterations), since they have no sideeffects.

Comment: What baffles me is: the JIT really doesn't optimize away these empty loops?!

Comment: @EddyG JIT will only optimize after the loop has been run a substantial number of times.

Answer (score 2):

It possible has something to do with the word size that your JVM uses. For a 32 bit word size, `ints` will require one word, whereas `longs` would require 2 words for storage. So basically reading `long` value is basically 2 reads, and writing them is again 2 writes.

Another thing is increment operation. JVM spec [doesn't have any instruction set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1-220) for `long` type increment. It has `iinc`, but don't have `linc`. So, the increment operation also has to go through `iinc` (that might again use 2 words, possible it can also result in 2 `iinc` operations). In all, arithmetics on `long` type are a little bit complicated as compared to that on `int` type. But certainly should not be of too much concerns. I guess these are possible reasons for slight slow result.

Answer (score 0):

Java's optimizer (Oracle JDK 1.8.0_60) is able to elide the int-loop, but it does not know how to optimize out the long-loop.

Changing `n` from 1000_000_000 to 2000_000_000 has no effect on the run time of the int-loop, but it causes the long-loop to run twice as long.